# How to disable smartd

Tags: osx, smartctl, smart

So I have a `Mac` which I installed `smartontools`, to see my `smart data`.

And I thought that `smartd` would be helpful in doing short tests on my `Mac SSD`

But I found out via `Google` that `smartd` only runs tests during `03:00am` and no way my Mac will be powered on at that time.

I understand that `smartd` is for `servers` which run `24/7` so there is no use of `smartd`.

So I would like to disable it and write my own simple `bash script` which runs short tests on my `Mac SSD`.

So is there any way I can disable smartd or remove it without affecting smartctl?

Answer (score 1):

> But I found out via Google that smartd only runs tests during 03:00am and no way my Mac will be powered on at that time.

I'm not sure your source but that conclusion is incorrect.

The time that tests run with smartd depends on what time you tell it to do so in the smartd.conf
Personally, I would keep using smartd but edit the test schedule in the file:
*/usr/local/etc/smartd.conf*

Please reference: [smartd.conf manual](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartd.conf.5.in).
See the **-s option** examples

> So is there any way I can disable smartd or remove it without affecting smartctl?

Yes, I would stop it from running by removing the associated LaunchAgent plist file.
Ex:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.smartmontools.smartd.plist  # Stop smartd process
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.smartmontools.smartd.plist  # Delete smartd startup plist
```

Your exact smartd plist file might be different but that worked for me.
Try searching yourself with:

```
grep -i smartd ~/Library/LaunchAgents/*.plist
```